# Server side MVC +Client side MVC

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, backbone.js

An application is both JS intensive and has a complex business logic +huge data flow that uses backboneJS to structure JavaScript code and there is a necessity for the server side MVC also (Spring in this case).

1. Is it a good idea to implement server side MVC (spring ) along with client side MVC (backbone) and are there any compatibility issues between them?
2. In case both can be implemented.How  am i going to coordinate the spring views with the backbone view.
3. How will client side MVC with template engine collaborate with 'View' of Spring.

Though this question has been asked before, I could not find suitable answer for this. Can somebody help me with a detailed answer?

Answer (score 9):

Backbone.js is primarily used for SPA's (Single Page Applications). Your backbone.js segments ('views') are rendered and re-rendered by data, that is fetched or changed. If your application is going to be javascript intensive, backbone is a great minimal framework that will help organize your application. However, backbone is not so simple when your javascript application becomes quite large. You have to have a thorough understanding of the fundamentals of javascript and have a programming decided pattern. Otherwise you application can become quite a mess even with the use of backbone.js.

Anyhow I digress. Think of you client side application (backbone.js driven) completely separate from your server side application (MVC driven). All your client application needs from your server application is the data. That is why backbone.js is built around a REST API. If you are looking to develop a large javascript application, I would look at using MVC 4's Web API for your REST API, and backbone.js to help organize and standardize your client application.

Comment: Thanks @Tyrone . I agree with you on the part where the backbone is required but my concern is regarding the usage of spring MVC backend for my application. whether there are any issues with using both

Comment: Sorry Satyaditya, I think my point was not clear. It should make no difference to what technology you are using for your server side, as long as your backbone.js application is working with a REST Api. Your server-side application and your client side application should not intertwine. All your client-side application is going to be doing is posting and getting data from your server-side application. Other than that, they have nothing else in common. In essence, server application will only be responsible for data being sent and received.

Comment: Your server (Spring MVC) will not be responsible for generating your views, backbone.js will generate your views. Take a look at the TODO tutorial, and you will get an Idea of what I mean.

Answer (score 4):

This article describes how to make an application architecture with both server side MVC and JS MVC , respecting the MVC pattern.
http://blog.javascriptmvc.com/?p=68