# Knockout or BackBone/Ember with asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, backbone.js, knockout.js, ember.js

We are evaluating to use a client side javascript framework, for a  social networking application with server side technology as asp.net mvc3. Please tell us what are the specific advantages(if any) of choosing knockout(with asp.net mvc) over ember.js or backbone.js.

Comment: You are bound to face problems. This is a fundamental issue. Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616455/server-side-mvc-client-side-mvc

Comment: I think the best way is to research yourself each library and decide what's hte best for you situation. Myself I prefer knockoutjs, it suits easily my style.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have any experience with any of those javascript frameworks but I know that knockout.js will be included in a future release of Asp.net MVC. You can find more info on the website: http://www.asp.net/single-page-application